# Adding new item in embed form Symfony doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have form created according to Symfony docs. If I do what I can, adding new Module does'n work - new items are ignored and they aren't send in request.

```
class Web extends AbstractModifiableEntity
{
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SelectedModule", mappedBy="web", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $modules;

public function setModules($modules)
{
    $this->modules = $modules;

    return $this;
}
public function getModules()
{
    return $this->modules;
}
public function addModule(SelectedModule $module){
    $module->setWeb($this);
    $this->modules->add($module);
}

public function removeModule(SelectedModule $module){
    $this->modules->removeElement($module);
}
}
```

---

```
class SelectedModule
{
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Web", inversedBy="modules")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="web_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
 */
private $web;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Module", inversedBy="moduleInstances")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="module_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $module;
}
```

---

```
class Module extends AbstractModifiableEntity
{
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SelectedModule", mappedBy="module")
 */
private $moduleInstances;
}
```

---

```
class EditWebType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder        
    ->add('modules', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new SelectedModuleType($this->modules),
            'label' => 'administration.webs.form.modules',
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true
    ))
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\CoreBundle\Entity\Web',
    ));
}
}
```

---

```
class SelectedModuleType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('module', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'ProfixwebCoreBundle:Module',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => $this->getModuleQueryBuilder(),
                'label' => false
        ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\CoreBundle\Entity\SelectedModule',
    ));
}
```

}

---

in twig

```
<div>
    <ul class="modules" data-prototype="{{form_widget(form.modules.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for child in form.modules.children %}
            <li class="modules_inner">{{ form_widget(child) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $collectionHolder;

var $addModuleLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_module_link button">{% trans %}administration.modules.edit.addModule{% endtrans %}</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addModuleLink);

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.default-hide').hide();

    $collectionHolder = $('ul.modules');
    $collectionHolder.find('li').each(function() {
        addTagFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addModuleLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addModuleForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        if($('#visiblePerex').hasClass('button_inactive')){
            changeTransVisibility('perex', 'hide');
        }
        if($('#visibleBody').hasClass('button_inactive')){
            changeTransVisibility('body', 'hide');
        }

    });
});

function addModuleForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
    var $newFormLi = $('<li class="translations_inner"></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    addTagFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
}

function addTagFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
    var $removeFormA = $('<a href="#" class="button">{% trans %}administration.modules.edit.remModule{% endtrans %}</a>');
    $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

    $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $tagFormLi.remove();
    });
}
</script>
```

---

I have no idea what is wrong and what I should to do.

---

EDIT:
I have missing `</div>` in other part of file.

Comment: Are you getting any error in Web Debug Toolbar?

Comment: are you mean Symfony toolbar, or some else? Symfony give not any error.

Comment: Is the <a> tag displayed? of is there a javascript error? Do you have jquery loaded on this page?